# How to redirect custom login & register url to node?

Tags: 8, .htaccess

I have changed below url's to Login & registration instead of default

So URL will be

```
http://www.domain.com/en/login-user
http://www.domain.com/en/register-user
```

I have multiple language so added language prefix.

I would like to redirect it to node via `.htaccess`

I tried

```
RewriteRule ^/login-user http://www.domain.com/en/test
```

But not working

Comment: `RewriteRule ^/login-user /en/test [L,R=302]` to redirect

Comment: This seems to be a very bad direction:
You want to redirect the "login-user" to "test" ?

Comment: Have you tried the redirect module? https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect

Comment: Yes @ssibal u  r right

Comment: So you say: AFTER successfully logging in or registering you would like to redirect them to a certain node page? (because this one is not clear to me)

Comment: No. Whenever user goes to login/register url it redirects to node. Not after login

Comment: Can we manage it w/o using module & via `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine :)

```
  # If your site is running in a VirtualDocumentRoot at http://example.com/,
  # uncomment the following line:
  # RewriteBase /

  RewriteRule /login-user /test [L,R=307]
  RewriteRule /register-user /test [L,R=307]
```